# How to add a number, say, 1 to a random real number in Mathematica?

Tags: random, summation

I wish to add, say, 1 to a random real number, say between 1/3 and 1/6.

I have used the following code in Mathematica, but it does not answer properly.

code:

p := RandomReal[1/6,1/3]

q:=p+1

p

q

In one run, Mathematica gives, for example:

0.182505

1.22942

Clearly, it is not adding.

Please help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5320330/what-is-the-difference-between-set-and-setdelayed

Comment: The definition of `p` should be `RandomReal[{1/6, 1/3}]`